# 5 MVC webApps sharing the same reports assembly (5 times)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got an IIS site with 5 MVC webApps in it sharing the same reports assemblies.
WITHOUT using the GAC, is there a way for all 5 of my webApps to use a shared/common bin folder with these reports assemblies in, without me having 5 copies of the assemblies in each web app's bin?
The assemblies are consumed via nuget, and the webApps are published to a folder in my deployment pipe.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies tipped me off to using a "probing path" in my web.config. I've added one of the webApp's bins on this path and deleted the duplicate assemblies in my build pipe.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element

e.g.

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```